# How can I display items on the extreme left and right of the page?

Tags: html, css, frontend, alignment, display

I'm working on making an e-commerce website. For the footer, I want to place the e-commerce's brand name on the top left, and the social media icon links on the top right.

The layout I want as follows:

[image: IMG1]

However, the footer currently looks like this:

[image: IMG2]

Here is what I have coded.

```css
.footer-top {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  float: left;
}

.social {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-top">
  <div class="name">
    <h1><span class="bigger">XXXX</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <!--Social media icons-->
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:flex;` to style navbar. Copy these code and paste in your **CSS** instead of code you have provided.

```css
.footer-top {
   display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-top">
  <div class="name">
    <h1><span class="bigger">XXXX</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <!--Social media icons-->
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook">fb</a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram">insta</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your layout wasn't what you expected is because you had `.name` in html but `.title` in css. Correct the class name and floats will work as well. Also there is no need to have `display: inline-block` and `width: 100%`. `<div>` is a block by default and occupies 100% of width.

That being said, with `flex` it is easier to align content vertically.

```css
.title {
    float: left;
}

.social {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-top">
    <div class="title">
        <h1><span class="bigger">XXXX</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
         <!--Social media icons-->
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook">icon</a>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram">icon</a>
    </div>
</div>
```